# Angular modules routing - not routing

Tags: angular

I very new to angular routing and lazy loading modules.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login-admin/admin-dashboard'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login-admin/admin-dashboard'

I don' know where I'm getting the error tho.

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignupAdminComponent,
    HeadersComponent,
    LoginAdminComponent
  ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**App.Routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login-admin', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login-admin',  component: LoginAdminComponent},
  { path: 'sigup-admin',  component: SignupAdminComponent},  
  { path: '',    
    loadChildren:  './components/dashboards/admin-dashboard/admin-routing.module#AdminRoutingModule'

  }

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    // AdminDashboardModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**admin-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    SideBarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [  ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

**admin-routing.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin-dashboard.component';
import { LoginAdminComponent } from '../../accounts/admin/login-admin/login-admin.component';
import { SideBarComponent } from './side-bar/side-bar.component';
import { ExtenstionAgentComponent } from './extenstion-agent/extenstion-agent.component';

export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [                                 
      {
        path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'admin-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },

];
```

Comment: Try putting / before your route names . And try it .

Comment: Right now I would expect http://localhost:4200/admin-dashboard to route to the AdminDashboardComponent.  It looks like you're expecting it to be http://localhost:4200/login-admin/admin-dashboard?

Comment: @HimeshSutharth thanks but I have try that  earlier

Comment: @KyleAnderson I actually expecting  localhost:4200/admin-dashboard and I was redirected to localhost:4200/login-admin/admin-dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things that are wrong as is.

As far as I understood from your code, you want to achieve something like following:

You want to have an `AdminModule` and delegate all of the routes starting with `/login-admin` to that module. From there, `AdminModule` will take over and create inner routes.

Based on this, you need to edit following parts within your code

`app-routing.module`

You have declared the root route (`''`) twice which is confusing for angular and tried to define `login-admin` route to `LoginAdminComponent` which is `AdminModule`'s job.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login-admin', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login-admin',  component: LoginAdminComponent},
  { path: 'sigup-admin',  component: SignupAdminComponent},  
  { path: '',    
    loadChildren:  './components/dashboards/admin-dashboard/admin-routing.module#AdminRoutingModule'
  }

];
```

Let's change it

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login-admin', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login-admin', 
    loadChildren:  './components/dashboards/admin-dashboard/admin-routing.module#AdminRoutingModule'},
  { path: 'sigup-admin',  component: SignupAdminComponent}
];
```

Also if you use angular v8+, you need to use following import statement instead.

```
loadChildren: () => import('./components/dashboards/admin-dashboard/admin-routing.module').then(m => m.AdminRoutingModule)
```

With this setup, we delegate every route that starts with `login-admin` to `AdminRoutingModule`.

Let's fix `AdminRoutingModule`

Again you declared the route `''` twice. Just delete the first one.

```
export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [                                 
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'admin-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },
];
```

Comment: great work :) That's exactly what I wanted! Appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to access a route that doesn't exist.

The route that you are trying to access is `login-admin/admin-dashboard` and that path doesn't exist.

You have to access `login-admin` in order to get the view with the component called `LoginComponent`.

If you want to access `AdminDashboardComponent` you need to access only `admin-dashboard`.

They are two different routes and they aren't nested.